# Qual a diferença entre %p e %d em linguagem C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, formatação, printf

- O que significa o endereço de memória que aparece com `%p` e o `%d` exatamente?
- Qual a diferença?

```c
int main()
{
    int teste = 10;
    int *ptr = &teste;

    printf("%p\n%d",ptr, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma correta para imprimir um ponteiro é o `%p`. Alguns compiladores exigem que faça um *cast* para `void *`. [Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Algumas implementações e dependendo da configuração do compilador permitem usar o `%d` de forma direta já que é sabido que um ponteiro pode ser convertido para um inteiro, outras só deixam se você fizer um *cast* para um inteiro, já que o `%d` é o *placeholder* para números inteiros e não para ponteiros.

Se você usa o `%p` o valor impresso leva em consideração que é um endereço de memória e imprime da forma mais apropriada possível, portanto deve ser em notação hexadecimal que é mais fácil de avaliar um endereço. Se usa o `%d` o endereço será impresso como um número em decimal, o que pode ser mais difícil de interpretar como um endereço, mistura conceitos. O número é o mesmo, só a forma de apresentar é que difere.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).