# Dúvida utilizando Ponteiros em C

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença usando %d no lugar de %p para retornar o endereço dos ponteiros. Usando o operador %d é uma boa prática de programação?

```
int a, *aPtr;

aPtr = &a;

printf("Digite o valor de a : ");
scanf("%d",&a);

/*
printf("O valor de a e : %d \n",a);
printf("O valor de *a e : %d \n",*aPtr);

printf("\n");

printf("O endereco de a e %d \n",&a);
printf("O endereco de *aPtr e %d \n",aPtr);
*/

printf("O valor de a e : %d \n",a);
printf("O valor de *aPtr e : %d \n",*aPtr);

printf("O endereco de a e : %p \n",&a);
printf("O endereco de *aPtr e : %p \n",aPtr);
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a diferença entre %p e %d em linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445047/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-p-e-d-em-linguagem-c)

Comment: Obrigado, conseguiu esclarecer algumas dúvidas!